# How can I list all groups on a system via PowerShell?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, powershell

The following 2 commands give the context of my question:

- **gcim Win32_Account | ft Name, SID** *lists all SIDs incl. their corresponding accounts on a system*
- **gcim Win32_UserAccount | ft Name, SID** *lists user accounts incl. their corresponding SIDs on a system*

How can the equivalent task be accomplished for *groups* in each case?

Comment: **gcim** is an alias for **Get-CimInstance** which can be checked via the command **Get-Alias -Name gcim**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-LocalGroup` should do the trick.

To have it match your current commands:

`get-LocalGroup | ft Name, SID`

Returns:

```
Name                                SID
----                                ---
Access Control Assistance Operators S-1-5-32-579
Administrators                      S-1-5-32-544
...
```

Comment: I found out a way to do this via **gcim Win32_Group |  ft Name, SID**, which lists one group less - **Access Control Assistance Operators S-1-5-32-579** - than yours. Any ideas on what the reason for this might be?


(For finding that command I searched for Cim-classes containing _group_ in their name via **Get-CimClass | Select-String -Pattern group**.)

Comment: Just as a heads up, `Win32_Group` will get all Active Directory groups if you are part of a domain.

Comment: It will take a *loooooooong* time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps things have changed since the question was asked and answered originally, but on 5 February 2021, moments before i write this answer, my up-to-date Windows 10 Administrator powershell replies to

```
gcim Win32_Account | ft Name, SID
```

with a list of three different entities:.

Users
Groups
Built-in Security Principals.

These are easily distinguished by the format of their SID:

Users have an SID like "S-1-5-22-0000000000-1111111111-2222222222-333[3]"
Groups have an SID like "S-1-2-3[3]"
Built-in Security Principals have an SID like "S-1-2-33-444"

Notes:

1. The actual digits will be different, of course. But the number of digits I wrote above is the number of digits that appears in each field of the SID on my machine. YMMV.
2. A digit in square brackets in my examples is one that might or might not be in the SID. For example, on my machine, users that are created by Windows, such as "Administrator" or "Guest," have 3 digits in the last field of their SID, while users that I create all have 4 digits in that last field.
3. On my machine, the last Group in the list is called "BUILTIN" and has SID S-1-5-32, and **all** of the Built-in Security Principals have an SID underneath that SID. For example, "Guests" is S-1-5-32-546 and "Users" is S-1-5-32-545.

In any case, you get both users and groups (and built-in security principals) from the single gcim Win32_Account powershell command on my machine.